# Picking the most recent post in WordPress with php

Tags: php, wordpress, selector, if-statement

I am trying to do an if/else-statement on my WP-template. But i can't seem to pick the right element.

I wan't it to look for the latest post on the blog. I already added a script that add a class of .first to the latest post.

What im  trying to do in dummy-php-language:

```
<?php
if ( class is .first) { do something to .first}
else () { do something to everything else }
?>
```

i've looked in the wp-documentation. But i can't seem to find anything that will select "*latest post*"...

Thanks

**Jonas**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very simple solution would be to keep a count of the post you're at, and do something if it's the first. In the `index.php`, in the `have_posts()` loop:

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : $count = 0; ?>
    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); $count++; ?>
        <?php if($count ==1) ?>
            // do something to first
        <?php else ?>
            // do something to everything else
        <?php endif; ?>              
    <?php endwhile; else: ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Getting a weird error. Jebus im a php-noob.
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ELSE in index.php on line 9.
Thats the <?php else ?>-line

Comment: I just {}-bracketed the if/else-statements and remove the endif; - then it works :) Thanks mr.

Comment: The `if` and `else` are missing a `:` after each of them(you can use curly braces instead though if you prefer, just remember to remove the `endif;` if you're changing parenthesis type).

Comment: Sorry about that, it was a copy-past and then deleting some of the stuff that didn't matter. I guess something that mattered got deleted as well.